# Redirecting Site Root URL to its Language Root Folder

Tags: plone

Environment: Plone 4.3.4.1 , plone.app.multilingual 2.0.0 (from github)

I have two Plone sites, both with p.a.m enabled, but they behavior differently when visiting to their site root URL. Say, visit http://www.site1.com/ will redirect to http://www.site1.com/zh , that is what I need. But http://www.site2.com/ will show its item listing, that I want it redirect to http://www.site2.com/zh. See the below picture for reference.

[image: Plone Root Folder]

How do I enable the auto-redirection to one of its Language Root Folder? Hints are appreciated.

**Edit After the Comment and Answer**:

Ulrich and Mathias are right for the hints. Here are some more details. First, when I select "Chinese" as my default site language, there is no "Root language switcher" under "Display" menu.

[image: Site Language]

When I select "English" as my default site language, then I can see and select "Root language switcher" under "Display" menu. Everything works as expected.

[image: Root Language Switcher]

Comment: What are your options under "Display"? LinguaPlone used to have an option "Root language switcher" that was responsible for doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like Ulrich mentioned, you can define the `language-switcher` View as default view on the plone root. This automatically redirects you to the desired language folder.

More Infos: https://github.com/plone/plone.app.multilingual/blob/2.x/src/plone/app/multilingual/browser/switcher.py

If you setup the a multilingual site, the default page of the plone root should be configured correctly: Check LanguageSetup: https://github.com/plone/plone.app.multilingual/blob/2.x/src/plone/app/multilingual/browser/setup.py#L245